# Are wire/belt cutter allowed to bring on-bag to plane?(not in luggage)

Tags: transit, luggage, legal, international-travel, travel-tools

I found some pocket tools that contains some sharp part for cutting seat belt I think, as TSA said no sharp thing are allowed on-bag but the belt cutter isn't something that can harm other, isn't it?

#### So can we bring pocket tool that contains belt cutter on-bag?

#### Belt cutter sample:

[image: belt cutter sample]

Comment: Indeed you can harm someone with a belt cutter. It's razor sharp.

Comment: @JoErNanO like cut the finger, cause I can't think out how can it harm since its at the inner side of the tool instead on the outer side like normal tool

Comment: Could you try? Yes. Would you get it on the plane? Probably not. All TSA officers have discretion with what to allow, and with less-known things it is fairly safe to assume a no is more likely if it gets flagged. You can never argue with TSA staff, their decision is final, no matter what the TSA website or anything else says.

Comment: @jacoman891 then how about other tools like screw drivers and ruler, can it be bring on plane? If yes why? They can also harm other, like you can smack someone's head by a screw driver

Comment: @Munucial The rules don't make sense, I don't make them. All I'm saying is that there isn't any concrete evidence you could take it on (it's not listed on the TSA site), and if you try, you risk having the object in question confiscated. My personal opinion is that confiscation is a likely outcome, but that's just a guess. No-one can tell you for certain.

Comment: @jacoman891 I knew that just pointing out something that don't make sense, and also their supporter has tells me that **although TSA make these rule, many TSA officer doesn't know it clearly**

Comment: @Munucial it's important to realise that these aren't rules, they're guidelines. TSA officers have complete discretion as to what to allow into the restricted area of an airport. Hence, it's always a good idea to err on the side of caution with these things.

Comment: @jacoman891 so it's better to put it in luggage whenever you can since there is lesser chance to have issue when you put tools in luggage right?

Comment: @Munucial Yes, absolutely.

Answer (score 1):

Manufacturers of keychain tools are aware of [TSA rules](https://www.tsa.gov/travel/security-screening/whatcanibring/items/multitools), which depend on the definition of a blade and sharp. In this case, the [manufacturer claims](https://www.mykeyport.com/moca-multi-tool) it meets TSA requirements.

> Best of all, the MOCA keychain tool is TSA-friendly so you can take it with you into any airport on all your adventures.

In general, you can check the manufacturer webpages of the specific tool you are considering to see if they make such a claim.

Comment: But how do we know if they specified **TSA approved** meant ok for on-bag or ok for in luggage?

Comment: @Munucial Because you can check-in any knife, so it would be pointless to approve that.

Answer (score 0):

There is no approval scheme for specific products. There are published guidelines which the TSA can (and does) change as they see fit. If the product *clearly* meets the guidelines in play at the time of inspection, it’s likely, but not guaranteed, to be accepted. TSA agents have the final say. You have no grounds for dispute, despite what some manufacturers imply.

In this case, the question of blade is the most significant. Bladed tools are not permitted for carry on, with some very limited exceptions (scissors under 4 inches from the pivot,at the time of writing).

It is not the manufacturers determination of what constitutes a blade, nor yours, that counts.

So, the rather dull outcome is - if you’re happy to risk losing a $10 tool, you can try. If you’re not, and have checked baggage anyway, pack it in there.

(As an example of manufacturers being potentially misleading, Leatherman lists ‘TSA Approved’ products, whilst the TSA themselves simply state that ‘Leatherman tools aren’t permitted for carry on’. The manufacturer adds a footnote saying they will not pay compensation for confiscation. That suggest they know they cannot stand by their assertion of approval).